# Is there a way to use the WPF Tree Visualizer in VS2013 without setting a breakpoint?

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2013

I know I can open the WPF Tree Visualizer by setting a breakpoint and aquiring a reference to a visual object. However, it would be really convinient to use the Visualizer by just selecting an open window of the running application. Is that possible somehow?

Answer (score 1):

Use [WPF Inspector](https://wpfinspector.codeplex.com/) Or [Snoop](http://blois.us/Snoop/) application.

1. Select the application.
2. Press `Ctrl` & select the control on running application.

Comment: I already know these standalone apps, however it would be great to be able to use the integrated Tree Visualizer instead. Thanks, though!